# What is Row Offset and Byte Offset in Hadoop Input file format? How the offsets are considered in Map-Reduce Program for Key-value Pairs?

Tags: hadoop

Text format, key-value format, sequence file format are the three standard file formats which are considered in Map-Reduce program. I need resolution on how the row offset and byte offset are considered in these three cases for deciding key value pair.

Answer (score 0):

There is no offset in `KeyValueTextInputFormat` and `SequenceFileInputFormat`.

Offset is used only in `TextInputFormat`, where it denotes **byte offset** from the beginning of the file.